# How to get all package with same product and brand in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a table 'stocks' with values below. I want to get all package with exactly the same product and brand inside as package 'a' (no more, no less).

```
||package || product || brand||
  a          aa         1
  a          bb         1
  a          cc         1
  a          dd         1
  a          ee         1
  b          aa         1
  b          bb         1
  b          dd         1
  b          ff         1
  c          aa         1
  c          bb         1
  c          cc         1
  c          dd         1
  c          ee         2
  d          aa         1
  d          bb         1
  d          cc         1
  d          dd         1
  d          ee         1
  d          ff         1
  e          aa         1
  e          bb         1
  e          cc         1
  e          dd         1
  e          ee         1
  f          aa         1
  f          bb         2
  f          cc         1
  f          dd         1
  f          ee         1
```

(1)I tried comparing each package to 'a' using FULL OUTER JOIN and got the expected result as it gives also the (null) rows which is missing on either 'a' or the other being compared.

However, when I removed the "where package = 'b'" on table B to compare 'a' to the table it does not return the (null) values.

(2)As a result, some package are being matched with package 'a'.

---

(1)

```
SELECT
 package, 
 product, 
 brand,
 case
  when A.brand = B.brand then 'Y'
  else 'N'
 end as match
FROM
 (select * from stocks where package = 'a') A
 FULL JOIN
 (select * from stocks where package = 'b') B
 ON A.product = B.product
ORDER BY A.package, B.package
```

---

(2)

```
SELECT package FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT(package) FROM stocks) X
LEFT JOIN(
 SELECT DISTINCT(C.package)
 FROM(
  SELECT
   A.package as p1, 
   A.product, 
   A.brand,
   B.package as p2,
   B.product,
   B.brand
   case
    when A.brand = B.brand then 'Y'
    else 'N'
   end as match
  FROM
   (select * from stocks where package = 'a') A
   FULL JOIN
   (select * from stocks) B
   ON A.product = B.product
  ORDER BY A.package, B.package
 )C
 WHERE match = 'N' ORDER BY C.p2)
)Y
ON X.package = Y.p2
WHERE Y.p2 IS NULL
ORDER BY package;
```

---

The expected result is only package 'e'

```
||product||
  e
```

Comment: have you tried using count() and group()?

Comment: Why 'c' is not in the expected output?

Comment: I tried using count(match), group by (package) to bring up all package with non matching rows. But as on (2) trial, the suppose to be (null) values to be matched as 'N' are missing

Comment: Hi Tejash, I missed out that one. I was supposed to change one of it's brand as well. Thanks for that

Comment: What version of sqlserver are you on.

Comment: Hi P.Salmon, I am using Oracle SQL Developer 1.5.1

Comment: Hmm Oracle sql devloper connected to sqlserver - is this really a sqlserver question. (and the version of sqldeveloper is irrelevant - it's the sqlserver version that is important)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `LEFT JOIN` with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` as following:

```
SELECT
    B.PACKAGE
FROM
        (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        YOUR_TABLE
    WHERE
        PACKAGE = 'a'
) A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        YOUR_TABLE
    WHERE
        PACKAGE <> 'a'
) B ON ( A.PRODUCT = B.PRODUCT
         AND A.BRAND = B.BRAND )
GROUP BY
    B.PACKAGE
HAVING
    COUNT(A.PRODUCT) = COUNT(B.PRODUCT) -- MUST BE SAME NUMBER OF ROWS
```

Also, you can use an aggregate function for it.

```
with TEMP_DATA AS (SELECT PACKAGE, 
LISTAGG(PRODUCT||BRAND) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PRODUCT) AS PRODUCTBRAND
FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY PACKAGE)
SELECT B.PACKAGE FROM TEMP_DATA A
JOIN TEMP_DATA B ON (A.PRODUCTBRAND = B.PRODUCTBRAND)
WHERE A.PACKAGE = 'a' AND B.PACKAGE <> 'a'
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=391cc9bd9e8184671c8fe1ce40de135b)

Cheers;

Comment: Hi Tejash! using the aggregate function solved my problem. thanks a lot for this!

Answer (score 0):

In order to get *exactly* the same, you need to count the products.  Assuming you do not have duplicates:

```
select tb.package
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by product, brand) as cnt
      from t
     ) ta join
     (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by product, brand) as cnt
      from t
     ) tb
     on ta.product = tb.product and
        ta.brand = tb.brand and
        ta.cnt = tb.cnt
where ta.package = 'a'
group by tb.package, ta.cnt
having count(*) = ta.cnt;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b8638c86304f3c69b33e356f3f7ab962) is a db<>fiddle.  This fiddle includes `'eplus'` which has an extra product -- and is not included in the results.

If you want to allow supersets, you can remove `tb.cnt` and the comparison to it.